# How do I let a non-admin user instantiate objects from a VB6 ActiveX Exe?

Tags: vb6, permissions, dcom, activex-exe

Question says it all really...

I have tried changing the "Allow non-admin users to run this program" setting on the property pages, and have also given the non-admin user in question what looks like the correct privileges in Component Services -> DCOM Config.

Is there anything else I can do ?

This is on Server2003 BTW.

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183607

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question a few days ago, but didn't answer because all I have is something for you to try. I expected someone else with knowledgeable answer to respond, but since you still have no answers I'll tell you the little bit I know. When our tech support department installs our app onto a computer running XP or Vista they log in with an administrator account the first time they run the app. Apparently that allows what ever needs to happen with the ActiveX DLLs to work. After that the users can log in with their regular account and the app is still happy.